# UITableView scrolling under iAd

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

i want to display iAd at the bottom of the screen..
i tried to add subView but the iAd showed in a cell and he hides him.

what should i do to make the tableView to scroll under the iAd?

my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self createAdBannerView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBannerView];

}

#pragma mark - ADBannerViewDelegate

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [self adjustBannerView];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self adjustBannerView];
}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
}

- (void) adjustBannerView
{
    CGRect contentViewFrame = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect adBannerFrame = self.adBannerView.frame;

    if([self.adBannerView isBannerLoaded])
    {
        CGSize bannerSize = [ADBannerView sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier:self.adBannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier];
        contentViewFrame.size.height = contentViewFrame.size.height - bannerSize.height;
        adBannerFrame.origin.y = contentViewFrame.size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        adBannerFrame.origin.y = contentViewFrame.size.height;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.adBannerView.frame = adBannerFrame;
        self.contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
    }];
}

- (void) createAdBannerView
{
    self.adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CGRect bannerFrame = self.adBannerView.frame;
    bannerFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;
    self.adBannerView.frame = bannerFrame;

    self.adBannerView.delegate = self;
    self.adBannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];
}
```

**EDIT:**

How do I prevent this?
i want to keep the iAd at the botton..

[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can start by posting the code that you are using ;)

Comment: is this a UITableViewController subclass or UIViewController subclass?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using auto layout, what I've done before is add an outlet to the constraint for the bottom space to superview (assuming you have a tableview within a view).

You can then just adjust the constraint in the callback when the ad is loaded by for example doing

```
tableViewBottomSpaceConstraintOutlet.constant -= adBannerView.frame.size.height;
```

where `tableViewBottomSpaceConstraintOutlet` is the outlet on the bottom space to superview constraint and `adBannerView` is your ad banner's view.

Comment: Having now seen the screenshot you've added, I wonder if you're using a Table View Controller rather than a view containing a Table View.  I'd rather use the latter as it gives more flexibility.

Comment: i pretty new to iOS devlopment, i would be greatfuk if you could explain me more about the tableViewBottomSpaceConstraintOutlet.

Comment: tableViewBottomSpaceConstraintOutlet is a name I've given to the outlet (when I ctrl-dragged in interface builder) attached to the constraint for the bottom space between the table view and the superview.  If you add a table view within a view, you can then add an outlet to the bottom space to superview constraint and adjust it using the above method.  To see how to add an outlet to a constraint in interface builder, see [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_Cross-Hierarchy_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_iOS_6).  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion from Apple is to add a container view to contain the ScrollView(TableView) and setup constraints between the fixed view and the container view

details here:
[Using Scroll Views with Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW2)